# splitting a dictionary in python into keys and values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I take a dictionary and split it into two lists, one of keys, one of values. For example take:

```
{'name': 'Han Solo', 'firstname': 'Han', 'lastname': 'Solo', 'age': 37, 'score': 100, 'yrclass': 10}
```

and split it into:

```
['name', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'age', 'score', 'yrclass']
# and
['Han Solo', 'Han', 'Solo', 36, 100, 10]
```

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Not that hard, try `help(dict)` in a console for more info :)

```
keys = dictionary.keys()
values = dictionary.values()
```

For both keys and values:

```
items = dictionary.items()
```

Which can be used to split them as well:

```
keys, values = zip(*dictionary.items())
```

**Note 0** The order of all of these is consistent within the same dictionary instance. The order of dictionaries in Python versions below 3.6 is arbitrary but constant for an instance. [Since Python 3.6 the order depends on the insertion order.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation)

**Note 1** In Python 2 these all return a `list()` of results. For Python 3 you need to manually convert them if needed: `list(dictionary.keys())`

Comment: Does python3 keep keys[idx] correspond to values[idx] for any idx ?

Comment: @VY: For both you should use `items()` instead, I'll add an example

Comment: @VY: but to answer your questions. Yes :)

Comment: seems like in python3, you will need to do `list(dictionary.keys())` and `list(dictionary.values())` if you want list type. Otherwise, you will get dict_keys and dict_values types.

Answer (score 3):

as a compliment to @Wolph answer,

its important to say that using `zip` may be much slower!

---

Added `split_with_tuple` - as `split` returns view objects as of python3

```py
In [1]: def split(d):
   ...:     return d.keys(), d.values()
   ...:
   ...:

In [2]: def split_with_tuple(d):
   ...:     return tuple(d.keys()), tuple(d.values())
   ...:
   ...:

In [3]: def split_with_zip(d):
   ...:     return zip(*d.items())
   ...:
   ...:

In [4]: d = {i:str(i) for i in range(10000)}

In [5]: %timeit split(d)
265 ns ± 12.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit split_with_tuple(d)
151 µs ± 772 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit split_with_zip(d)
950 µs ± 15.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple below method, it will separate all the keys in to list

```
    newdict = {1:0, 2:0, 3:0}
    a= [*newdict]
    print(a)
    [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This only partially answers the question for the keys, but not for the values. Further it would be nice if you could do a speedtest like the other answer and see how efficient it is.